# How to include Variables from one template in another

Tags: symfony, twig, shopware6

I have an Online shop (It's Shopware 6 [Symfony, twig]).
in Product detail Page i Show the variation. and when they out of stock i make them grey:

[image]

but the Problem is in Product-Listing page, I can't grey out the out of stock products in Quick view because my Variable won't load:

[image]

I was Wondering if i can include somehow the Variables like:

```
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator.html.twig' with {notinhere : page.unavailable} %}
```

**UPDATE:**
This code is in my Configurator.html.twig :

```
    {% set notinhere = page.unavailable %}
    <div class="product-detail-configurator-option {% if option.id in page.unavailable %}grau-labels{% endif %}">
        {% block page_product_detail_configurator_option_radio %}
            <input type="radio" name="{{ group.id }}" value="{{ option.id }}" class="product-detail-configurator-option-input{% if isCombinableCls %} {{ isCombinableCls }}{% endif %}" title="{{ optionIdentifier }}" id="{{ optionIdentifier }}" {% if isActive %} checked="checked" {% endif %}>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

And then this file included in my buy-widget.html.twig

```
{% if page.product.parentId and page.configuratorSettings|length > 0 %}
    <div class="product-detail-configurator-container">
        {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator.html.twig' %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And Product-detail page using this (buy-widget.html.twig) and the it works just fine in Product-detail page.

my quick-view twig includes this:

```
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig' %}
```

so, i tried to add with `notinhere : page.unavailable` on both sw_include and it still not working.
What is the problem here?!

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it with `with`

Comment: but i'm getting null in my page

Comment: Make sure `page` is defined then

Comment: @DarkBee hi, i have updated my question. can you please check it out please. thanks

Comment: Where are you using the `notinhere` variable? I see usage of `page.unavailable` in your `configurator.html.twig` file, but you are not passing the `page` variable to the template - since using `with` only passes variables that are explicitly defined while omitting all other variables. Additionally, variables passed to the templates are limited to the template and `block` scope they are defined on. I guess show the full code, so we can determine where the break is, since the snippets do not provide enough context.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue: https://twigfiddle.com/lihpqz, so something else may be occurring elsewhere in the templates/controllers that we cannot see.

Comment: i set this ({% set notinhere = page.unavailable %} ) to my configurator.html.twig and tried to get the variables in my buy-widget.html.twig like this ( {% if page.product.parentId and page.configuratorSettings|length > 0 %}
<div class="product-detail-configurator-container">{% sw_include @Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator.html.twig' with {
 notinhere: page.unavailable
 }  %}
 </div>
{% endif %}
                    <pre>
                        {{ dump(notinhere) }}
                    </pre> )   but i'm still getting null

Comment: If I am reading you correctly, setting a variable in a template that is out-of-scope from another will not work. You would need to define the variable in the parent template scope using `{% set %}` before passing it to the `include` otherwise use the global scope of `page`. Using `with` only passes the arguments as declared to the `include` template, it does not set a new variable on the parent template.